# why $[F(a):F(a^2)]=2?$

Tags: field-theory

Prove that  if $[F(a):F]$ is odd then  $F(a)=F(a^2)$

**My attempt** : I got answer [here](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Estatmath/oldqp/Sol/Algebra%20IV%20MS%20Sol%202014-15.pdf)

But i have some confusion in the given answer

My confusion is given below and marked in red

> **Problem $\mathbf{1.(a)}$.** State true or false with justitication. For fields $F\subseteq K$, $\alpha\in K$, if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$.
>
> *Proof.* Suppose that $F(\alpha)\ne F(\alpha^2)$. Cleary this implies $\alpha\notin F(\alpha^2)$. We can also conclude that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F(\alpha^2)$ is $x^2-\alpha^2$. Hence $\color{red}{[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)]=2.}$ But we know that $[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)][F(\alpha^2):F]$. Hence we must have $2\mid[F(\alpha):F]$ and thus we arrive at a contradiction. So $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$ and the given stament is **true**.$\square$

**My confusion** : why $[F(a):F(a^2)]=2?$

**My thinking** : Here $f(x)=x^2-a^2$  is reducible in $F(a^2) \implies  a\in F(a^2)$

Put $x= a$ , then $f(a)= a^2 -a^2 =0$

So $[F(a):F(a^2)]=1$

Comment: As $\alpha\not\in F(\alpha^2)$ [that is the assumption] we know that $X^2-\alpha^2$ is NOT reducible over $F(\alpha^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $f(x)=x^2-a^2$ is not reducible as $a\notin F(a^2)$ by assumption (otherwise $F(a)\subseteq F(a^2)$ and hence $F(a)=F(a^2)$ as trivially $F(a^2)\subseteq F(a)$). In particular, you cannot put $x=a$ as this is not an element of your base field $F(a^2)$.

Hence, indeed $\min_{F(a^2)}(a)=x^2-a^2$ and consequently $[F(a):F(a^2)]=\deg(f)=2$.

Comment: there is some mistake in ur profile **NOT**  Cantor. statement ....The scientist does not study nature because it is useful; he studies it because he delights in it, and he delights in it because it is beautiful.-**Henri Poincare**  check my profile

Comment: @jasmine I found this quote a long time ago; I might've to check it again. Thanks for pointing out!